# Deploying .NET application through RDP

Tags: .net, deployment, rdp

I work for a company which mainly deploys .NET software on remote windows servers. These servers are reachable only by RDP. It is quite cumbersome to deploy to these, especially, when the target machine sits behind an already remote terminal server. The basic workflow now looks like this:

- Create deployment package (Setup project for desktop apps, publish option for web) on development machine.
- Start RDP with the "remote filesystem"-option enabled.
- Copy app to remote (browsing remote filesystem is a real PITA)
- Repeat when current server is not target (in case of going through a remote TS)
- install on target machine

You can see, this is quite tedious. Are you aware of tools/whatever that could speed this up? The remote servers are mostly owned by other companies, so my access is mostly limited there.

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at the answer to <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867180">this</a> question.

Comment: So that basically means creating power-shell scripts manually? That'd be a bummer, I hoped there would be a better solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy files to a remote server via RDP using a script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867180/copy-files-to-a-remote-server-via-rdp-using-a-script)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at 'Click-Once' - it's not suitable for all types of applications, but works very well where it is suitable.

Comment: I didn't find anything relevant regarding the two (RDP and click-once) combined. Care to elaborate?

Comment: No, it's nothing relevant to RDP, just that it avoids some of the things you said were a pain - remote file browsing, etc.  And if most of the reason  you're doing this is to upgrade existing apps, then it could avoid that too, by doing the upgrades automatically.